# Android: LocationManager when Airplane mode on

Tags: android, geolocation, xamarin.android, locationmanager, airplane-mode

I am testing the `location` part of my app with various configurations. In `AirPlane` mode I don't get any message sent to `ILocationListener`, good or bad, from the following `LocationManager` on an Android 2.2. In this case the bestProvider is "network".

How can I determine if there simply is no way to get a location so that I can inform the user? When there is a network or GPS it all works fine.

The code I use (**Mono for Android** C#) is:

```
            var cr = new Criteria ();
            cr.Accuracy = Accuracy.Coarse;
            cr.PowerRequirement = Power.Low;
            cr.AltitudeRequired = false;
            cr.BearingRequired = false;
            cr.SpeedRequired = false;
            cr.CostAllowed = true;
            string serviceString = Context.LocationService;
            locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService (serviceString);
            var bestProvider = locationManager.GetBestProvider (cr, false);
            locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates (bestProvider, 5000, 500f, this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as `this` is your Location Listener you can see the state in `onProviderEnabled (String provider)`, `onProviderDisabled (String provider)` or `onStatusChanged (String provider, int status, Bundle extras)`. Read this [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) for further Information, what each state means

Answer (score 0):

You can not use any kind of Communication like GPS,GPRS in AirPlane Mode. Airplane mode is a setting available on most cell phones, smartphones and other electronic devices that, when engaged, suspends many of the device's signal transmitting functions – thereby disabling the device's capacity to place or receive calls or text messages – while still permitting use of other functions that do not require signal transmission (e.g., games, built-in camera, MP3 player).

Comment: I am pretty sure GPS is still working on most phones. It might take much longer to get a fix but it works in airplane mode.

Comment: well, even if it works then user can only store the data in to local device for future use, unless user change the profile mode.

Comment: It should though throw a message saying it can't get anything.

Comment: GPS clients are entirely passive receivers of the GPS timing signals, the client doesn't transmit anything to the satellites and therefore GPS will continue to function just fine in Airplane mode.